# touchpad won't respond immediately

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

This is more of a pet-peeve item, but I recently updated from Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04, and it looks great, but my touchpad is a bit "sticky". It doesn't move right away, and I have to drag it a little before I get a response. I have a Dell Inspiron N5110. Any tips? It worked just fine in 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue with my Dell Inspiron 5720. Worked great in 13.10, just upgraded to 14 and experiencing the issue for the first time. Sticky is a good term to describe it. I am about to revert back to 13 if I cannot find a fix for this.